# How to make exe file from java but executable on computer which has no java

Tags: java

i tried to convert from jar file to exe file with jsmooth, launch4j.

it works on my computer well.

but it doesn't work when it executes on other computer which has no java

Does anyone know the way to convert jar file to exe file which is executable on the computer has no java?

Comment: Are you looking for self contained packaging explained in [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using https://www.excelsiorjet.com/ for a long time.

It creates a Windows .EXE style application that you can install using normal installer tools.  They have a decent trial period, try it out.

Comment: Can it, and how does it bundle a JRE? That's what the OP is asking - without that information this looks more like an advertisement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yes, it can make exactly what the OP asked.